# JavaScript pop up window (cross-origin frame issue)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have button on Opportunity on click oh which i am opening a VF page window .After opening the URl becomes

https://c.cs16.salesforce.com/apex/VFpage

On Click of save button i am closing the opoup window and refreshing parent window but when i close it it show a javascript popup error after closing the window.It says

```
A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

Blocked a frame with origin "https://cs16.salesforce.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I know this error is coming because the URL are different but i dont know how to solve this issue.

Can someone tell me how to solve that issue.Its urgent for me.

**EDIT**

Hey

I am using below code for closing the window and rereshing...

```
window.top.close();
     window.opener.location.href="/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}";
```

For opening a pop window from custom button below is the code

```
    window.showModalDialog('https://cs16.salesforce.com/apex/PDFViewer?id={!Opportunity.Id}','',
      'dialogHeight:600px;dialogWidth:950px;center:yes;');
```

but when i open my pdf viewer page URL becomes

https://c.cs16.visual.force.com/apex/PDFViewer?id=006f0000004fKcj

You have any suggestions.???

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just making the button a URL rather than OnClick JavaScript:

```
/apex/MyPage?myParam=foo
```

Alternatively, you could just make the button a Visualforce page but that does not accept parameters and the page must be tied to a controller extension.

Comment: I need to write Javascript to as I am doing other things too . second option I didn't understand. Can you explain in detail..thanks mate

Comment: Are you redirecting in the parent frame? window.top.location.href = "/apex/MyPage";

Comment: Hey i have updated my code..Can you please see what i am doing and suggest me something..

Comment: This appears to be related to your problem: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008yuaIAA

Comment: This is still not solved...Can you please help me..??

Comment: Did you look at the link provided? I saw two solutions posted. Unfortunately the most recent one is in a blog which is no longer being maintained. However that solution also won't work from a standard VF page either, so might not work for you anyway.

Comment: No solution worked for me..Can you suggest something else....I really need to solve this asap...:(

Comment: If we use a URL then in that case..That cross domain error is not coming but my i am unable to refresh my parent page :(