# When I change a VisualForce page ContentType, can I somehow give it a file extension?

Tags: content, visualforce, extension

Currently reading about [Using Custom ContentType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_content_type.htm).

I see that, instead of serving an HTML page, I can instead serve some other media types, such as Excel or RTF.

However, when I create the page, I can't give it an extension.  And visitors to the resulting VF Page's URL (at least in Chrome) will be prompted to download the page as a file, still without an extension or even a hint of the MIME type (unless they saw some hint at whatever they clicked to visit the URL).

Moreover, even if they know (for example) that the file will be an Excel file, Excel may not be able open the file if they don't first give it the correct extension (e.g. The Excel file in the example will not open at all with ".xlsx", and will open with a warning with ".xls").

Is there some way to "fix" the page so it will download with an appropriate extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a filename (and thus, extension) via the [Content-Disposition Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) - see [this answer to a similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4121/67).

Comment: Works.  :-)  Two notes:  1. If you aren't making an attachment, you don't need to include "attachment" in the dispoisition; 2. If you are using a standard controller, you can just as well put this in a controller extension.