# Setting title for a vf page with rendered as PDF to view title when it loads

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to change title of a visualforce page which is rendered as PDF. But adding title attribute to apex:page tag, 
 or even adding title in head tag,

```
<apex:page controller="NMAT_PaymentReciept" title="Payment Acknowledgment Receipt for NMIMS Application" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf">
```

[image]

As of now its showing pages Name

Please help...this is frustrating. 
Thanks for time!

Comment: Check out this link : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/how-can-i-specify-a-file-name-for-a-visualforce-generated-pdf

Comment: Thanks for reply but No !!! These articles explain about how to set name of file being downloaded....But i want to change title of VF page that is rendered as pdf so that when i load that vf page i see that title on top.

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136043/change-pdf-title-in-browser-window says even if you could set the title in the PDF meta data Chrome would _not_ show it (but Firefox would).

Comment: This is not duplicate. All the other posts are similar but not of them solves the issue mentioned by Dnyaneshwar. The highlighted text always shows the page name and title is ignored when rendering VF page as PDF. See this post which is similar and has no solution yet - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DD8SIAW