# I can set a dynamic filename of PDF(Visualforce page). but only Japanese characters are not shown

Tags: visualforce, pdf, dynamic

The codes are below. I can set the name of pdf dynamically and when I use the "save as" the name of pdf is set the filename.
But the filename will be set if it is an alphabetic or numeric character, but it will not be displayed correctly if there are spaces or if it is a Japanese character.

How can I fix this? `The Field3__c` is a text field.

- When the Field3 is "abcdef", PDF name is "abcdef.pdf".
- When the Field3 is "12345", PDF name is "12345.pdf".
- When the Field3 is "あいうえお", PDF name is ".pdf".
- When the Field3 is "abc123", PDF name is "abc123.pdf".
- When the Field3 is "abc 123", PDF name is "abc.pdf".
- When Field3 is "12 ab あ 1a", PDF name is "12.pdf".

----VF page----

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Mitsumori__c"
extensions="MitsumoriPDFController" applyBodyTag="false">
```

----Apex----

```
public class MitsumoriPDFController {
public MitsumoriPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

Mitsumori__c acc =  [SELECT Id,Field3__c FROM Mitsumori__c];
String accNum = acc.Field3__c;
String fileName = accNum + '.pdf';
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'inline; filename=' + fileName);}}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed this help article and does selecting a particular font help? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321277&type=1

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I added a code below to Apex. after that 
When the Field3 is "abc 123", PDF name is changed from  "abc.pdf" to "abc 123.pdf". Space is recognized. but Japanese is not recognized.　
When the Field3 is "あいうえお", PDF name still is ".pdf".

---Added to Apex---
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('Content-Type', 'application/pdf; charset="UTF-8"');

Comment: I changed the Field3_c from text to Rich text area. after that 
When the Field3 is "あいうえお", PDF name is "_p_     __p_.pdf".
How Can I solve this?

Comment: I know nothing of this, but my sleuthing found [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4121/81648) to the question entitled, "How can I specify a file name for a Visualforce generated PDF".  In the answer, @DanielBallinger states, _"If there are non-ASCII characters or [the filename] is longer than 78 characters it needs to be Hex encoded (RFC 2184)."_

Comment: I found a splution. the solution is URLENCODE(adding encord). I changed the below. I can show Japanese as filename.
-----------
public class MitsumoriPDFController {
public MitsumoriPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

Mitsumori__c acc =  [SELECT Id,FileName__c FROM Mitsumori__c];
String accNum = acc.FileName__c;

String accNum2 = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(accNum, 'UTF-8');

Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'inline; filename=' + accNum2);}}

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = 'おはよう.pdf';
String fileName2 = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(fileName, 'UTF-8');
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'inline; filename=' + fileName2);
```